# Splitting a text file into a list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, csv, text, split

I'm currently attempting to break a .txt file into a list of lists for easier sorting. However, I can not seem to get my splitting function to work. The Text file will look something like this

```
First Name        Second Name        Age        Class Room Number        GPA
Louis             Darter             16         1                        3.5
Emma              Handzo             15         1                        3.6
Jing              Luo                25         2                        2.0
Charles           Xavier             13         2                        3.0
Scott             Summer             10         1                        3.1
```

And here is what im currently attempting to do:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('ARCC_Challenge1.txt', 'rb'), delimiter=' ')
split_text = []
for line in reader:
     split_text.append(line[1:-1])

print split_text
```

Ideally, I'd like to get the output in a format that looks something like `[[First Name 1, Last Name 1, Age 1, class room number 1, GPA 1],[First Name 2, Last Name 2, Age 2, class room number 2, GPA 2]...]` Mycurrent code produces an array, but its full of blank spots and many values seem to have `\t` attached to them. 
Any ideas that you might be able to give me to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print map(str.split,open('ARCC_Challenge1.txt', 'rb'))
```

I think should basically do what you want

you may need to call `list` on the result depending on the version of python

alternatively if you are more of a list comprehension guy

```
print [line.split() for line in open('ARCC_Challenge1.txt', 'rb')]
```

you save your lines instead of printing them

```
lines = ...
#then you can skip some with normal slices
print lines[3:]
```

Comment: Quick question. If i wanted to use this approach while skipping the first few lines of header, how would i do so?

Comment: @PhilipR .call `nex(f)`t on the file object

Comment: Excellent. This did precisely what i wanted it to do. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing your file is tab delimited, not space delimited? Try the following:

```
import csv

with open('ARCC_Challenge1.txt', 'rb') as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t') #\t = tab delimited
    next(csvin, '') # skip header
    split_text = list(csvin)
```

Comment: Clearly is left justified.

Comment: This is close, but still not quite what i need. It seems to me that the text file has both spaces and tabs in between columns. With your code, i get the output [[], ['First Name         Second Name', '', 'Age', '', 'Class Room Number', '', 'GPA'], ['  Louis', '', '     Dartez ', '', '16                     1                        3.5']...]

Comment: @PhilipR. if you can guarantee that no columns will be more than one word - then you can use Joran's approach - that should work for your data

Comment: would `skipinitialspace=True` work when you have a different delimiter?

Comment: @Padraic it will - but I don't believe it'll solve the issue of picking up empty columns

Comment: @JonClements, yep, did not really read the output properly. Think `delimited` should be `delimiter` also ;)

Comment: @Padraic I don't know what you could possibly mean... *whistles innocently* :p